# Having troubl in git merging a branch into another branch that has already been merged with another branch... fatal error or MERGE_MSG

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Just to put it out there, I'm completely green at coding and at GIT.  In the assessment I'm doing I have to create three branches apart from the master.  I create and checkout one branch called "drawings" and add and commit it (this branch is a subdirectory [with the eponymous name "drawings"] with three jpgs moved into it).  Then I go back to master and then create and checkout a second branch called "pictures" and add commit it (a subdirectory named pictures with two jpgs in it).  I add and commit this.  Then I checkout master and then create and checkout a branch called "together".  Here is where the trouble starts.

I use
`git merge drawings`
After that, I'm supposed to merge "together" with "pictures".  What I do is

```
git checkout together
```

then

```
git merge picture
```

it takes me to a MERGE_MSG screen.  I have no clue what to do in there or how you exit it.  I'm on Windows 10 and I'm using the Ubuntu Terminal.

Even if I close the terminal and reopen and get back to the master branch, I get fatal errors no matter what command I use even it is "git log" or "git status".

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need screenshots of anything, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first merge, there was no real merge, git `fast-forwarded`. The second merge does require a real merge and so it tries, succeeds and then you go into an editor where you will set up a comment for the revsion. So you should write whatever comment you want, save and exit. If it's nano, the options are at the bottom... if it's vi/vim, it's a little more complex... check any guide on how to use vi to write something, save and exit.

Comment: I appreciate the clarification.  That kind of makes sense because of what I was reading in the status before I tried to do the second merge.

I got to the MERGE_MSG prompt.  Now the codes at the bottom say things like ^G for "Get Help" or ^X for "Exit".  I don't know what that means.  Does that mean Shfit + G or Shift + X?

Comment: I looked up nano and figured out that it was Ctrl + X.  Thank you for giving me the name Nano.  I didn't know the name of the editor so I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to search for help with it on Google.